# Prolog list of elements within a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to have all my C's in the same list,

Like:

`?- channels(C,3).
    C = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]] ;`

but what i get is this:

`?- channels(C,3).
   C = [[1, 2]] ;
   C = [[1, 3]] ;
   C = [[2, 3]] ;`

My code is:

```
channels([C],N) :- range(1,N,L), combination(2,L,C).


range(I,I,[I]).
range(I,K,[I|L]) :- I < K, I1 is I + 1, range(I1,K,L).


combination(0,_,[]).
combination(K,L,[X|Xs]) :- K > 0,
   el(X,L,R), K1 is K-1, combination(K1,R,Xs).

el(X,[X|L],L).
el(X,[_|L],R) :- el(X,L,R).
```

Please help me

Comment: Please put more effort into stating what you want. Currently, it is all guesswork

Comment: Looking your desired output and your actual output, I guess it would be `channels(LC,N) :- findall(C, (range(1,N,L), combination(2,L,C)), LC).`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, but your solution worked, so you understood it as you should, but thank you very much.

Comment: @VHdk: Don't know if this question would be useful to anybody else. Anyway I put the previous comment as an answer as it is what you where looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking your desired output and your actual output, it looks like you want to collect all solutions of `combination(2, L)` with L ranging from *1* to *N*:

Therefore, you can use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) to accomplish that:

```
channels(LC,N):- 
  findall(C, 
   (range(1,N,L), 
    combination(2,L,C)
   ), LC).
```